# Algorithm to minimize the distance between boats and fishing spots

Tags: algorithm

Each boat can only go to one fishing location and each fishing location can only have one boat.
Every fishing spot contains an estimated amount of fish, and every fishing boat has a performance rating.
No crew will accept to be assigned a spot with fewer fish than a spot assigned to a crew with a lesser rating.
Boat may onlytravel parallel to the axes of the (2-dimensional) coordinate system,
The computation should be done in a way that,first,  maximises  the  amount  of  fish  captured,  second,  minimises  the  total  distance  travelled,and, third, minimises the sum of the ratings of the crews.

An example of distance would be covered would be

```
(200,100) to (250,100) == 50
(100,200) to (150,150) == 100
(50,50) to (0,100) == 100
```

In case there are more boats than fishing locations I tried to compute all possible combinations and see which minimized the total distance but the process takes a long time since the number of boats and fishing locations can be 1 <= n <= 4000

I don't know how to come up with a more efficient solution that considerably reduces program execution time.

If you need more clarification please ask.

Comment: Is this homework? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions if it is

Comment: @jakub Yes, I’m just looking for some help because I’ve tried a lot and really don’t understand how to do this more efficiently.
I hope I'm not breaking any rules.

Comment: It would be helpful if you updated your question to include the code you have already tried. This should be a minimal, reproducible example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for more information.